# Removed Entity is again found by findFirstByAttribute in MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm implementing Favorite scenario using in my app using MagicalRecord a CoreData Wrapper. I'm searching for the value that if the attribute is found in my entity it'll remove it as fav or else it'll add it to fav. Do here `DX *foundDX = [DX MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"code" withValue:cell.DXCodeName.text];` foundDX is the value I'm checking for.
I've a UISearchBar added to my tableView. So when the view is loaded it displays the already fav items which use can un-fav. If user search and select an item it successfully adds it to fav and successfully remove it from data model. But if I again click on fav button it crashes.

```
   if (!foundDX.code) {
        //If we are always getting into here that means that either foundDX is nil
        //or the code is nil so you need to verify the logic around that.
        if (indexPath != nil)
        {
            if (!_AddEditDX) {
                self.AddEditDX = [DX MR_createEntity];
            }
            [self.AddEditDX setCode:cell.DXCodeName.text];
            [self.AddEditDX setDescriptions:cell.DXDescText.text];
            [self.AddEditDX setIsFav:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
            [self.favDXArray addObject:self.AddEditDX];
            [self fetchFavDX];

            [cell.DXFavButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"Added to Favourite" duration:1.0f];

        }
    } else if(self.favDXArray.count > indexPath.row) {
        //You can get rid of the if(foundDX.code) because this is the else block to not having it so we must have it.
        //Only thing to worry about is the array size
        NSLog(@"count is: %ld and row is: %ld",_favDXArray.count, (long)indexPath.row);
        DX *tempDX = [self.favDXArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tempDX MR_deleteEntity];

        [cell.DXFavButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_blank"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.favDXArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"Removed from Favourite" duration:1.0f];
    }
```

By Applying some breakpoints I found that:
Suppose code is `E45` and `foundDX` didn't found it for the first time and added it to the data model. Then on pressing fav button again it removes it and in real it did removed it. But if I again tap on fav button the foundDX is still `E45` and hence it crashes. But if I close the app and run it again `E45` is no longer there.
**UPDATE**

I've updated the code above. I was using `fetchFavDX` in `viewDidLoad` so I tried calling it in the method as updated in the code above. Whereas in `fetchFavDX` I'm doing this:

```
-(void)fetchFavDX {
    self.favDXArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[DX MR_findAllSortedBy:@"code" ascending:YES]];
}
```

Now it is working fine for the first two times meaning add/remove/add/remove. After that it only runs the block `if (!foundDX.code)` meaning it is not getting into the else part.

Comment: Can you update the above with the crash log? Please

Comment: @HarmVanRisk it's `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'` which indicates that the object is removed which is correct if I run the app again. But if it's the same run it crashes with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that the self.favDXArray count is longer than the indexpath.row so that there is something there to actually remove/retrieve. It would be something like this:

```
if(self.favDXArray.count > indexPath.row){
    DX *tempDX = [self.favDXArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tempDX MR_deleteEntity];
    [cell.DXFavButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_blank"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.favDXArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"Removed from Favourite" duration:1.0f];
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}
```

**Update**

```
if (!foundDX.code) {
 //If we are always getting into here that means that either foundDX is nil 
//or the code is nil so you need to verify the logic around that. 
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        self.AddEditDX = [DX MR_createEntity];
        [self.AddEditDX setCode:cell.DXCodeName.text];
        [self.AddEditDX setDescriptions:cell.DXDescText.text];
        [self.AddEditDX setIsFav:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

        [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        [self.favDXArray addObject:self.AddEditDX];
        [self fetchFavDX];

        [cell.DXFavButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"Added to Favourite" duration:1.0f];

    }
} else if(self.favDXArray.count > indexPath.row) {
//You can get rid of the if(foundDX.code) because this is the else block to not having it so we must have it. 
//Only thing to worry about is the array size
    NSLog(@"count is: %ld and row is: %ld",_favDXArray.count, (long)indexPath.row);
    DX *tempDX = [self.favDXArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tempDX MR_deleteEntity];

    [cell.DXFavButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_blank"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.favDXArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"Removed from Favourite" duration:1.0f];
}
```

Make sure that the method to get foundDX is returning what you're expecting. Also make sure that the add/remove is leaving you in the state you expect to be in i.e. that you have the content you have added or removed

Comment: This answer gave me something and I can sense I'm close to finishing it. Can you see the updated question and update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @TalhaCh I have updated as best I can with what you have presented. Hopefully it'll help you

Comment: Now If I run the project it runs it for the first time meaning add>remove>add then it seems as if `[self.favDXArray addObject:self.AddEditDX];` is not adding the value. Because the count is zero after that. This is because it is repeating I think.

Comment: I updated the code to remove         [self fetchFavDX]; in the deletion because this was most likely setting self.favDXArray to nil

Comment: Nope the result is the same! Some how the count of `favDXArray` is `0` for the second time it tries to remove the object.

Comment: What is the count at the log?

Comment: When the first time I click star button it's `count is: 0 and row is: 0
` where it successfully adds it to fav. Then if I again click on it log shows `count is: 1 and row is: 0` and successfully removes it. Then I again click it and log is `count is: 0 and row is: 0` it shows Added to Fav and then when I run again shows `count is: 0 and row is: 0` and from there it only runs the else block which is added to fav.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124815/discussion-between-harmvanrisk-and-talha-ch).